# Testing authorization_code flow from spring-security-examples github repo

Tags: spring, spring-security

Here's a link to the repo: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/authorization-server

The client_credentials flow works as laid out in the readme. But I can't seem to make the authorization_code flow work.

Entering the username `user` and password `password` into the login form from http://localhost:9000/login leads to a whitelabel error page as seen below
[image]